# Random Class - assign object to another object

Tags: java, random

Im having trouble understanding this class and everything ive seen hasn't really helped.
Ill make my question as simple as possible.

If i have examiner 1, examiner 2, examiner 3 and
route1, route 2, route 3.

Both being Strings.

How would i randomly assign an examiner to a route? 
This is probably a silly question but i just cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: Can you show us some code, like your classes for example? What exactly are `examiner`s and `route`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the examiners in a `List` and use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to shuffle it.

After it is shuffled, `listOfExaminers.get(i)` will be assigned to the corresponding route [You can also place routes in a list - to make it as generic as possible, but you only need to shuffle one list].

Comment: Duh!.. Thank You. I think i was looking too much into it

Answer (score 2):

You can store all 3 examiners and all 3 routes in 2 different String arrays, and then, use a Map to store the Examiner-Route combination. You can then use the `Random` class to randomly assign a route to a given examiner.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List<String>` containing the examiners, and a `List<String>` containing the routes. Shuffle the list of routes (using [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)).

Now the examiner at index `i` is associated to a randomly chosen route at index `i`. You can of course create a class (`Examination`) containing the examiner and the corresponding route, and create an instance of this class for each pair.